# Powershell: Import CSV and then export it afterwards

Tags: windows, powershell, userscripts

First of all I would like to thank you for helping me or at least reading my post

I have an CSV file name as Users with two values

```
firstname,lastname
John,Doe
Jane,Doa
```

I would like to use these values and create many values with it and afterwards export it to another CSV

This is the code

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\Temp\users.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $firstname = $user.firstname
    $lastname = $user.lastname
    $username = ($firstname.ToLower()+"."+$lastname.ToLower()) -replace '\s',''
    $email = $username+"@email.com"
    $Location = "Paris"
    $ou = "OU=Users,OU=ORG,DC=test,DC=local" 

    Select-Object $firstname,$lastname,$username,$email,$Location,$ou | export-csv C:\Temp\userstest.csv
}
```

The issue with this code is: I get an empty CSV as export

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-exporting the csv with every single row, this is causing your issue.

Instead, let's shift the order of commands and make this work.  Furthermore, you could use Calculated Properties to make this even shorter, like this.

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\Temp\users.csv
$Users | Select firstname, lastname,`
  @{l='username';exp={($_.firstname.ToLower()+"."+$_.lastname.ToLower()) -replace '\s',''}},`
  @{l='email';exp={"$($($_.firstname.ToLower()+"."+$_.lastname.ToLower()) -replace '\s','')@email.com"}},@{l="Location";exp={"Paris"}}, `
  {l='ou';exp={"OU=Users,OU=ORG,DC=test,DC=local"}}  | export-csv c:\temp\some.csv
```

Tested it on my PC and it worked just fine!

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot 
The email value is empty. it should use the username@email.Com

Comment: To safe memory, I would suggest to also stream the input (not assigning it to a variable), meaning: `Import-Csv C:\Temp\users.csv |Select firstname, lastname ...`